# DocuSign Integrator Key Vs API Username

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to setup a Demo account with DocuSign for the company that i work for and ran into a question if i should create a new account or create a integration key within the existing test account.

Please help me understand Integrator Key and Account ID with DocuSign.

Below is what I understood.

Considering Google's parent(Alphabet) as an example, Alphabet will be assigned with a Account with DocuSign which will be shared across the board and each entity like Google, YouTube, Google Maps will be given a unique integration key to use services provided by DocuSign.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

[image]

Thanks,
Reddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DocuSign accounts / users / integration key (client_id) system is quite flexible.

A customer (a company or organization or person) has one or more accounts. For a large corporation, each major business unit will often have its own account with various account-specific settings.

A user (someone who has sender capability and/or administrative rights) has access to one or more accounts via their email/password (or token).

Signers and other recipients do not need accounts. They are free and unlimited.

An integration key is normally usable by any user for any account.

Each major application should have its own integration key.

When an app starts, it should look up the current user to see which accounts the user has access to. If there is more than one account for the user, the app should either ask the user which account should be used or obtain the information from the app's settings.

Comment: So are you saying client can create multiple accounts and assign each module with an account in docusign?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please submit it as a new question